# data.frame with plotly selected points in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have generated a plot with ggplot, from which I need to select specific points, so I can perform downstream analyses on them (mockup code and image below).

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(2000, 10, 3), y=rnorm(2000, 10, 3))
nms <- row.names(df)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, key = nms)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "lasso")
```

[image: lasso_selection]

I would need to store in a separate data frame the ids (rownames, in this case) of the points I have selected.
I have seen shiny widgets that embed the selection into the UI side of the app and I even considered copy-pasting the contents of the embedded table into a csv, (crude as that may be) but the tables shown understandably have a limited amount of rows and most of the points I select are not there.
Since I am certain the info must be stored somewhere, can anyone please explain how to access it?
Many thanks!

Comment: Since you're essentially using R to create HTML and desire to use R *from* HTML, you need client-side linking: either Shiny or RMarkdown. With either option, you don't have to add it to the plot or image, you can use it to create an object in the global environment, create a csv, or just print to the console. Check out the information and link from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072388/interactively-choose-points-with-lasso-in-ggplotly)